# Passing a type to a class library generic method that's unknown - why does it work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, generics

I'm working on a C# .NET solution with lots of re-usable assemblies.  Three of these are:

- a WinForms assembly
- a webclient class library
- an assembly that contains the data model classes

I have a generic method in the class library as such:

```
namespace Company.WebClient {
  public class GetData<T>()
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

However, when I call the method from within the WinForms assembly, I pass in a Type that the class library won't know, since it's contained in the data model assembly:

```
namespace Company.WinFormsApp {
  public class App 
  {
    public void Main()
    {
      Company.WebClient.GetData<TypeFromTheDataModel>();
    }
  }
}
```

Surprisingly, it seems to work.  But why does it work?  The webclient assembly has no hard-coded reference to the data model assembly so I'm surprised that it doesn't report 'type not found' or some such error. Is this a safe way of working, or should I add more references to my project (i.e. from the class library to the data model)?

Comment: Doesn't it just treat the `TypeFromTheDataModel` as an `Object`, since you're using a non-restricted type parameter? That's how it works in Java, at least, iirc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library doesn't need to know anything about the type - it's not trying to use any members of the type, after all. At execution time `GetData` *could* find out about `T` - but at compile-time it doesn't need to.

Just think - if this *didn't* work, then LINQ to Objects would be completely broken, as you could only use it for sequences of system types!

Basically, it's entirely safe to do this.

Comment: OK, I think I get it.  But bear with me would you?  Within the class library I deserialize into a List<TypeFromTheDataModel> using JSON.NET - so presumably at runtime, the class library must have to find out about T ?

Comment: @CarlosP: Yes, but it can do that using `typeof(T)`. It doesn't have any compile-time requirement to know about that type though.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, am suitably informed

Answer (score 1):

This is, basically, the point of generics. The **CLR** knows at runtime the particular class defining the type you want to use for `T`; and the code you've written in `GetData` says what to do with objects of type `T`. The **CLR** provides the stitching so that you don't have to think about it.

Note that in this example you place no **constraints** on `T` (there is no `where` clause). This means all you can do with `T`-type objects is treat them as `object`, which isn't that useful. Had you constrained them to, say, implement an interface `IMoreInteresting`, it would certainly be the case that both library and caller would need access to the definition of `IMoreInteresting`.

Comment: Think JonSkeet just beat you to it but I appreciate the extra info.  I think I get it now - but see my comment to Jon's answer; I still don't quite get how the webclient library is then able to 'use' the data model class to deserialize JSON objects into objects from it. Is that just because all the assemblies get loaded into memory together at runtime?

Comment: @CarlosP yes, and the fact that in .NET, even at runtime, types carry around their *metadata* with them. Once a type is loaded by the CLR, it can do anything with it.

Comment: Appreciate the clarification - it makes more sense now